# formatting files with sed/ python/ etc

Tags: python, formatting, replace, sed, solaris

I have a file which is created by a program. It contains html code and propitiatory calls to other software. In this file there are many variations of:

```
<td>$GETR("wp","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>
```

so it could be:

```
<td>$GETR("dc","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$NO$GETR("","3")$NA$NOTE()$</td>
```

or:

```
<td>$GETR("tc","1")$Yes$NOTE()$</td>
```

etc

I have created a script which properly formats these files but this bit I am stuck with.
I want the script to search through the file and if it finds more that one GETR between  and  then to put each GETR on a new line tabbed, so like:

```
<td>
    $GETR("wp","1")$Yes
    $GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$ 
</td>
```

Now if there is only one occurrence of GETR between:

```
<td> and </td>
```

I would like it to be changed to GETC, so:

```
<td>$GETR("tc","1")$Yes$NOTE()$</td>
```

would become:

```
<td>
    $GETC("tc","1")$Yes$NOTE()$
</td>
```

Any ideas how I can do this? I currently have a bash script which does some moving around which calls a python script to replace some formatting.

I am using Sun Solaris 5.10

Thanks

Comment: "Now if there is only one occurence of GETR between and I would like it to be changed to GETC.

" can you please explain this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are desiring?

```
>>> x='<td>$GETR("wp","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>'
>>> if x.count("$GETR")>1:
    x=x.replace("$GETR","\n\t$GETR").replace("</td>","\n</td>")


>>> print x
<td>
    $GETR("wp","1")$Yes
    $GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$
</td>
>>> x='<td>$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>'
>>> if x.count("$GETR")>1:
    x=x.replace("$GETR","\n\t$GETR").replace("</td>","\n</td>")


>>> print x
<td>$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>
```

In that case try this

```
if x.count("$GETR")>=1:x=x.replace("$GETR","\n\t$GETR").replace("</td>","\n</td>")
if x.count("$GETR") == 1: x=x.replace("$GETR","$GETC")


>>> x='<td>$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>'
>>> if x.count("$GETR")>=1:x=x.replace("$GETR","\n\t$GETR").replace("</td>","\n</td>")
>>> if x.count("$GETR") == 1: x=x.replace("$GETR","$GETC")
>>> print x
<td>
    $GETC("","2")$No$NOTE()$
</td>
>>> x='<td>$GETR("wp","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>'
>>> if x.count("$GETR")>=1:x=x.replace("$GETR","\n\t$GETR").replace("</td>","\n</td>")
>>> if x.count("$GETR") == 1: x=x.replace("$GETR","$GETC")
>>> print x
<td>
    $GETR("wp","1")$Yes
    $GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$
</td>
>>>
```

Comment: Yes kindoff, but I was a little unclear I've modified the description, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comment from Potong, this should substitute only lines with $GETR.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat ff
<td></td>
<td>$METR(dsdsd)$No(dsds)</td>
<td>$GETR("wp","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$No$NOTE()$</td>
<td>$GETR("dc","1")$Yes$GETR("","2")$NO$GETR("","3")$NA$NOTE()$</td>
<td>$GETR("tc","1")$Yes$NOTE()$</td>

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -e '/$GETR/s/<\/td>/\n<\/td>/' -e 's/$GETR/\n$GETR/g' -e 's/$GETR/$GETC/g' ff 
<td></td>
<td>$METR(dsdsd)$No(dsds)</td>
<td>
$GETC("wp","1")$Yes
$GETC("","2")$No$NOTE()$
</td>
<td>
$GETC("dc","1")$Yes
$GETC("","2")$NO
$GETC("","3")$NA$NOTE()$
</td>
<td>
$GETC("tc","1")$Yes$NOTE()$
</td>
```

In your Solaris box, you may not be able to substitute with new lines like `\n`. If that is the case, press enter manually for new line substitution.

```
sed -e '/$GETR/s/<\/td>/\
<\/td>/' -e 's/$GETR/\
$GETR/g' -e 's/$GETR/$GETC/g' ff
```

Comment: Nice work, but it may have unintended side effects. Hint there may be other `td`'s and `GETR`'s .

Comment: Thanks for your help but there are some problems, I only wanted GETR to be replaced with GETC when there is only one GETR tag between each <td> and </td>

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem you are facing? Can you post some sample data where this fails?

Comment: its fine now the other answer works for me, thanks for your help